# Simple way to convert list to dict

Tags: python

Please, tell me the simplest way to convert list object to dictionary.
All parameters are looks like this:

```
['a=1', 'b=2', ...]
```

And I want to convert it into:

```
{'a': '1', 'b': '2' ...}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use:

```
>>> x
['a=1', 'b=2']
>>>
>>> dict( i.split('=') for i in x )
{'a': '1', 'b': '2'}
>>>
```

Answer (score 5):

For each element in the list, [`split`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) on the equal character, and add to dictionary using the resulting list from `split`.